# how to save image into server.mappath on client side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one button as below code

```
<input id="Save" style="Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 8px; WIDTH: 128px; TOP: 36px; HEIGHT: 24px"
                                        onclick="return save_onclick()" type="button" value="Save Image" name="save">
```

the function for click event is as below

```
<script language="javascript" id="clientEventHandlersJS">
function save_onclick()
{
   document.AxuEyeCam.SaveImage("test.jpg");       
}
</script>
```

By these way it is saving image in desktop folder of computer,

but i want to save image inside my web application folder name PatientImages,
maybe using `server.mappath("");` blau blau blau....so can anybody give me the code how it is possible to save image or some idea how it can be possible..

thank you very much...

Comment: provide your saveimage code

Comment: document.AxuEyeCam.SaveImage("test.jpg");  this code will save image into the desktop folder of pc...but i want this to be save in web application folder. for eg. patientimages....as on the server side i did something like follows string strfilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/PatientImages/" + strfilename + "")); so i want this thing to be done on client side as jscript

Answer (score 1):

I don't think directly it is possible. You need to create a web-service for that and then use the service from jquery or java-script.

Example:-
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/uploadwithcsharpws05032007121259pm/uploadwithcsharpws.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var strfilename = "test.jpg";
document.AxuEyeCam.SaveImage("<%= Server.MapPath("~/PatientImages/" + strfilename + "") %>");
```

Comment: I try with you code....it run without error when but it is not saving image inside the server PatientImages folder....what would be wrong?

Comment: what is AxuEyeCam ? Does it capture image from web cam ?

Comment: yes it capture image from webcam and also save that image in the desktop so just let me know how can i save into the server?